# SSIS/visual studio- using derived column transform to count distinct values and sort by two variables?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have three columns of data- incident_ID, date, state.

The **incident_ID** are each unique, date is in year format only and ranges from 2013 to 2016, states are in no particular order and repeat if an incident occurs w/in the same state in the same year.

[image: sample view of data]

I'm going to be combining this data w/ another table, but first I need to organize the data to better match the other table's format- which is laid out showing the year, state, and dollars spent per state. So for 2013, I would have 51 rows (each state + DC) and each state would have a dollar amount- then rinse/repeat down the table through to 2016.

I'm pretty new to `SSIS`/`Visual Studio`, but from my understanding I should be able to use a **Derived Column** Transform to accomplish this.... but I don't know how to get there.

Is there a way to use **Derived Column** to 'count' and rearrange the data in order to show how many incidents occurred per state in the given year?

Answer (score 0):

There is no **aggregate** (like `SUM,Count,Min,Max`) functionality in Derive Column`enter code here`.For count, you can use `ROW COUNT` Task or you can insert the data into SQL table and then you can call the result value in derived column.